# Managing investments for multiple goals

Tags: stocks, investing, starting-out-investing, investment-strategies

I have been investing towards multiple goals, like Retirement, House, Car, Vacation etc. So I make monthly deposits against each of these goals. But I have a single fidelity account for investing, so each of these deposits end up mixed together in a single account. The problem is I can't manage how each individual goal is doing and it gets bit messy to implement different investing strategies for different goals, using the same brokerage account.

I was wondering what approaches people follow to bucket-ize their investments against different goals, especially with brokerage accounts like Fidelity etc. Having a separate brokerage account for each goal is probably too extreme, but a single account doesn't seem manageable.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

> I have been investing towards multiple goals, like Retirement, House, Car, Vacation etc

What if the stock market drops 10% or even 20% just before you are ready to buy a car or go on vacation?

You're up a very malodorous, very toxic creek and lack a paddle, that's what.

Thus, short term goals like "Car" and "Vacation" should be **saved for** in on or more of:

1. a high yield savings, and
2. high yield CDs.

My rule of thumb is that any goal less than 5 years away goes in Savings.

> But I have a single fidelity account for investing, so each of these deposits end up mixed together in a single account.
>
> I was wondering what approaches people follow to bucket-ize their investments against different goals, especially with brokerage accounts like Fidelity etc.

Spreadsheet programs are **perfect** for this.

One column per goal, **two** rows per month.

- In one row, apportion the contributions per goal.
- In the second row, record the account's gains or losses apportioned per goal.

Add another column that is the Sum of all your goals.  At the end of every month, the Sum column should equal the account balance.

> Having a separate brokerage account for each goal is probably too extreme,

That depends on how much you have invested.

Comment: "account's gains or losses apportioned per goal" -- I think the question is how you apportion those

Comment: @BenVoigt OP gets to decide that.  If he transfers $500 in March, then he chooses how much of that $500 goes into the March row of the Car column, the Vacation column, the Retirement column and the House column.

Comment: Right, apportioning contributions is not a problem.  Gains and losses are less straightforward, especially as OP says different strategies are in use for each goal (consistent with different time horizons)

Comment: @BenVoigt "*different strategies are in use for each goal*".  OP knows how much he's contributed to the account, what funds are in that account, and how much he's contributed.  He's just got to do the math apportioning it out, which we can't do for him.

Comment: @BenVoigt the main problem is that He's Doing It All Wrong, and the only way we can fix that is to tell him to Do It The Right Way (which is what got BobBaerker voted down.

Comment: @RonJohn appreciate the answer. Will definitely fix my approach based on your inputs on investing vs savings. Though, I still have long term goals that are served through investing and not savings. The spreadsheet way of tracking multiple investments would obviously work and I understand the math involved, but doesn't seem ideal due to the continuous effort required to maintain it. I was just hoping there are easier ways of managing investment for individual goals since it seemed like something lot of people would want.

Comment: @shreyj "*Though, I still have long term goals that are served through investing and not savings.*" Naturally.  My 401(k) and IRA funds sure aren't in savings accounts...

Comment: If deposits are commingled in a single account, apportionment is arbitrary whether in one's mind or in the columns of a spreadsheet. One could say that for goals 1, 2 and 3 it's 70/20/10% and 5 minutes later one could say that it's 60/25/15%.  True apportionment only occurs if there are segregated accounts. It doesn't make a lot of sense to me to be saving for specific goals.  You just save and invest and your needs take precedence (car blows up) and your wants are secondary (vacation, home ownership).  As you can afford them, you achieve them.

Comment: RonJohn - any answer with a word I need to look up gets a +1 from me. "malodorous" must have been an SAT word I missed. Nice

Answer (score 2):

A brokerage account is for investing.

If you're just saving for different goals, open multiple money market accounts, either with Fidelity if they pay a decent rate of interest or elsewhere.  Then link them, where possible.

Comment: Looks like you are answering a different question (should I invest or just save in an interest-bearing account for short-, medium-, and long-term goals?) and have not even partly addressed the question: how to invest for multiple goals at once.

Comment: @BenVoigt he's answering the meta-question, "Is investing the right way to accumulate money for short to medium term goals?"

Comment: @RonJohn: But "How do I track investments toward multiple goals at once?" is a perfectly reasonable question (someone can easily have multiple long-term goals) so there is no excuse for avoiding it.

Comment: @BenVoigt "*But "How do I track investments toward multiple goals at once?" is a perfectly reasonable question*" which is why I answered **both** questions in my answer... :)

Comment: The only edit I'd suggest is to focus on the brokerage account "investing" being for the long term, i.e. retirement. (Do 20 year olds say "I am renting but wish to buy at 40?)  All else are shorter term goals which go into MM, as you said. The unspoken implication is that the OP is making this far more complex than it needs to be. And the sister question [Downside of having multiple brokerage accounts?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/106823/having-multiple-brokerage-accounts) asks about the downside to doing something that should be avoided in the first place.